# Hyperledger Fabric Client Registration failed

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I am new to Hyperledger Fabric and i am trying to register the fabric client with the server locally. here is what i have done so far.

```
go get -u github.com/hyperledger/fabric-ca/cmd/...
fabric-ca-server start -b admin:adminpw
```

after that i got the logs

> 2017/12/11 13:26:09 [INFO] Home directory for default CA:
>   /home/akash/fabric-demo 2017/12/11 13:26:09 [INFO] Listening on
>   http://0.0.0.0:7054

then i tried to register the fabric client with server by using the following commands

```
export FABRIC_CA_CLIENT_HOME=$HOME/fabric-ca/clients/admin
fabric-ca-client enroll -u http://admin:adminpw@localhost:7054
```

and I got the following logs

> 2017/12/11 13:28:48 [INFO] Stored client certificate at
>   /home/akash/fabric-ca/clients/admin/msp/signcerts/cert.pem 2017/12/11
>   13:28:48 [INFO] Stored CA root certificate at
>   /home/akash/fabric-ca/clients/admin/msp/cacerts/localhost-7054.pem

but when i tried to register the client then i got the following error

```
fabric-ca-client register --id.name admin --id.affiliation org1.department1 --id.attrs 'hf.Revoker=true,admin=true:ecert'
```

> 2017/12/11 13:37:05 [INFO] Configuration file location:
>   /home/akash/fabric-ca/clients/admin/fabric-ca-client-config.yaml
>   Error: Error response from server was: Authorization failure

on the fabric-server side i got the following logs

`2017/12/11 13:37:05 [ERROR] No certificates found for provided serial and aki`

Can anyone tell what i am doing wrong here.

Comment: Which version of Go do you have installed?  Using "go get" will pull down v1.0.x of fabric-ca and it only support Go 1.7.5.  If you attempt to use Go 1.9 with fabric-ca v1.0.x you'll get the error you posted above.

Answer (score 1):

The sequence to obtain new user certificates is to 1) register and then 2) enroll.

For the bootstrap admin (enrollment id:admin) this is already registered when the CA server is started (thus providing the secret when starting the instance). As such, you are able to run the enroll command for admin.

Not too sure what you are trying to do here, but if you are:

1) trying to register a new user. You have to use a new unique enrollment id (not admin)

2) updating the affiliation of the admin enrollment id, refer to the fabric-ca-client command to update an identity (https://hyperledger-fabric-ca.readthedocs.io/en/latest/users-guide.html)